# XPATH 1.0 find duplicate based on two elements/keys

Tags: xml, xpath

Here is my XML

```
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8'?>
<cmps>
      <cmp>
         <name>abc</name>
         <id>302</id>
      </cmp>
      <cmp>
         <name>abc</name>
         <id>370</id>
      </cmp>
      <cmp>
         <name>abc</name>
         <id>073</id>
      </cmp>
      <cmp>
         <name>abc</name>
         <id>302</id>
      </cmp>
      <cmp>
         <name>ab</name>
         <id>370</id>
      </cmp>

</cmps>
```

===================
In the above xml, want to find out all the duplicates based on name and id  element.
so this xml has one duplicate element which has same name and id.  but below xpath expression shows two duplicate element , can somebody correct the expression...any help is appreciated

cmps//cmp[id= (following-sibling::cmp/id) and name= (following-sibling::cmp/name) ]

Output of above xpath expression:

```
<cmp>
         <name>abc</name>
         <id>302</id>
</cmp>
<cmp>
         <name>abc</name>
         <id>370</id>
</cmp>
```

Expected output :

```
<cmp>
             <name>abc</name>
             <id>302</id>
</cmp>
```

Comment: In what kind of environment are you executing these XPath queries?  I don't think this can be done all in a single ordinary XPath query.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `not()`:

```
//cmps//cmp[not(id= (following-sibling::cmp/id) 
                and name = (following-sibling::cmp/name))]
```

Result:

```
<cmp>
  <name>abc</name>
  <id>302</id>
</cmp>
<cmp>
  <name>abc</name>
  <id>073</id>
</cmp>
<cmp>
  <name>ab</name>
  <id>370</id>
</cmp>
```

Comment: Thank You !! However, this expression will return all unmatched element. I need expression which either return duplicate element or nothing..

Comment: @JitendraKumar Don't mind, just a misunderstanding - I thought you would like to get all elements and only remove the duplicate. It would be good if you could add the expected output in your question. If I get it right, you want to get the duplicate in case there's a duplicate, and in case there is no duplicate the xpath should return nothing?

Comment: @JitendraKumar: I read your request the same way mattias_h did and spent time clarifying it to be easier to understand.  I've rolled-back the edit because I obviously misunderstood your question too, but you really have to state your question more clearly.  Try using the verb "select", for example, for what you wish the XPath to do.  Thanks.

Comment: @matthias_h : You got it right. Pls select the duplicate element if exist based on two element name and id else return nothing .

Comment: kjhughes: Updated the xml with expected output and what my xpath expression is giving , pls let me know if you have any question

Answer (score 0):

It seems, we can not accomplish this task in xpath 1.0